# Android: add DONE key to soft keyboard deprecated attribute

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to add a `DONE` key to the soft keyboard so that it will hide when the user is done adding text to an `EditText`.

The thing is that, from other answers here, I saw that adding the following to the XML file will do the thing:

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
 android:singleLine="true"
```

**It actually WORKS fine**, and the `DONE` key is showed....however, Android Studio is complaining, telling that `android:singleLine="true"` is **deprecated**, use `maxLines = 1`.

Well, if I change `android:singleLine="true"` with `maxLines = 1` **it DOES NOT WORK** and the `DONE` key is not showed.

Am I missing something here?? (Android Studio 2.3.3 I am using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`android:singleLine`** is <s>***Deprecated***</s> .You should use <kbd>**maxLines**</kbd> with <kbd>**inputType**</kbd> .

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:maxLines="1"
android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: yes, THANKS, it works now, for any other person reading this.....it will not work without `inputType`